# Xubuntu Mac theme?

Tags: 12.10, themes, xubuntu, macosx

I have Xubuntu 12.10, and I would love to have a mac theme on it. I have been looking at this:
http://www.noobslab.com/2012/11/install-mac-os-x-theme-on-ubuntu-1210.html
...and I'm wondering if it would work on xubuntu. If not, are there any suggestions or options? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need a theme for XFCE, Xubuntu's desktop enviroment.

Look around on http://xfce-look.org/

This one looks nice:

http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/Cratos-lion?content=151866

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will work with XFCE (your window manager). It seems to be made for gnome (wich is not part of xubuntu).